# Visual Studio 2013 don't start multiple projects with IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I've Solution with multiple Projects in my Visual Studio Professional 2013 (Update 2).
I wish to start two of them by multiple startup project option:

1. Web Forms application which hosts silverlight application
2. WCF Service

I'm using IIS Express and Internet Explorer for browsing.

Everything was working but suddenly from one day I've stared getting this error at startup:

> "Process with an Id of 7612 is not running."

Than IIS Express is closing (not icon tray) and in my output :

> The program '[4956] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
>   The program '[7612] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

It seemed to my like Visual Studio was unable to invoke IIS Express. I have tried to invoke it by myself with command to run all my two sites:

> "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"
>   /apppool:Clr4IntegratedAppPool

And they run correctly. Now when IIS Express is already up, I'm running again my projects from Visual Studio correctly. But it's very inconvenient for me because if I stop debugging I must reopen my IIS Express again... 
Could You drop me a hint what's wrong ? Should I install normal IIS and try with him ?

Here's my applicationhost.config:

```
    <sites>
        <site name="IDReader.WCF" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Dokumenty\IT\PracaMagisterska\IDReader\IDReaderWCF" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:4267:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="IDReader.Web" id="4">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="D:\Dokumenty\IT\PracaMagisterska\IDReader\IDReader.Web" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5066:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>

        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>
```

Comment: That is just the way it works, annoying...

Comment: Seriously ? But there must be some explanation why it's not working..